# Why I2C ultra-fast mode support only write operation

Tags: i2c, communication, digital-communications, protocol

Below image is from TI I2C training.

It says that Ultra-fast mode supports write only and omits some standard I2C feature.

This does not say why it is supporting only write and what are the features it is omitting from standard I2C and why it omits those features.

May I know why?

The second thing is in High speed mode I2C requires active pull up.

Can some one please help me to understand active pullup and the devices used for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UFm is write only because the I2C bus standard says so, but does not say why.

If we want to start guessing why Ultra Fast-mode (UFm) is write-only, the reasoning is slightly circular.

The standard open-drain signaling limits the communication speed as signals have slow rise time, but it allows all devices to drive the bus. To get faster speeds, the bus driver signaling is changed from open-drain to push-pull. This does not allow more than 1 device to drive the bus, and having support for allowing that would be complex to allow a bus turnaround to change the driver for the ACK bit. Many devices are write-only, and are not required to give any feedback back. Therefore, it misses any feature that requires reading or feedback, even the ACK bit is ignored as it can't be checked, but it is still included in the data transmission protocol.

So if you want speed, make the output push-pull, don't allow anything but unidirectional communication, and you have basically a high speed unidirectional mode.

The High Speed (HS) mode also uses faster clock than previously, but not so fast than UFm. At this speed, pull-up resistors would be too slow for rising bus edges. Therefore active bus pull-ups must be used to make the rising edge faster. The bus capacitance is charged faster with a 3mA current source as active pull-up, than a resistor that only initially provides 3mA and charges the bus capacitance with exponential RC waveform. Or a resistor which charges bus faster with more current would consume more current when bus is held low.

Comment: @ Justme,Thank you.May I know what kind of IC's are used for active pull up.I did a google search,did not find any.

Comment: HS mode chips should have the internal active pull-up built into them. You should not need any separate ICs for that.